# searching and storing specific part of file

Tags: linux, string, file, shell, search

I've problem in searching and storing specific part of a file into a variable in bash shell.

Here it's one sample of my files:

```
From root@machine2.com  Mon Jan  7 16:56:50 2013
Return-Path: <root@machine2.com>
X-Original-To: smsto+9121403571@machine2.com
Delivered-To: smsto+9121403571@machine2.com
Received: by machine2.com (Postfix, from userid 0)
        id 43C191A1ECE; Mon,  7 Jan 2013 16:56:50 +0330 (IRST)
Date: Mon, 07 Jan 2013 16:56:50 +0330
To: smsto+9121403571@machine2.com
Subject: =?us-ascii?Q?Testing\=08?=
User-Agent: Heirloom mailx 12.5 7/5/10
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Message-Id: <20130107132650.43C191A1ECE@machine2.com>
From: root@machine2.com (root)

My note ..
blah blah ...
```

What i need to do is to Storing some of these fields into variables (parameter like FROM, SUBJECT and EMAIL BODY)

for FROM and SUBJECT fields it was easy to search and get the data.
But for EMAIL BODY, as you see there is no any Labels to search for it ... so i was thinking one of possible ways to get the email body would be searching for FROM label and then using its line number to get EMAIL BODY from next line to end of file.

unfortunately I'm not that familiar with linux command to do such thing.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sed` to print from the blank line to the end of the file:

```
$ sed -n '/^\s*$/,$p' file

My note ..
blah blah ...

# Command substitution to store into a variable  
$ body=$(sed -n '/^\s*$/,$p' file)

$ echo $body
My note .. blah blah ...

# Remember to quote variables to respect newlines
$ echo "$body"

My note ..
blah blah ...
```

If you don't want to include the first blank line use:

```
$ sed -n '/^\s*$/,$ {/^.*[^ ]\+.*/,$p}' file
```

Or strip all blank lines in the body:

```
$ sed -n '/^\s*$/,$ {/^.*[^ ]\+.*/p}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to approach the problem is to look for the first empty line (which occurs right after the 'From:' line you talk about) and print everything after that. You can do this using `awk` and setting a null record separator. For example:

```
BODY=$(awk 'NR>1' RS= file)
```

However, the advantage/problem of the above is that blank lines will be discarded. If this is undesirable, here's a method that should satisfy:

```
BODY=$(awk 'i==1; /^$/ { i=1 }' file)
```

Then:

```
echo "$BODY"
```

Results:

```
My note ..
blah blah ...
```